# How do you read a CSV file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a .csv file in my r studio. The name of my file is data_raw. Could someone help me out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please try searching to see if your question has already been answered before posting a new question. Many common questions already have answers on StackOverflow. If you cannot find an answered question that fully captures the substance of your problem, please provide a [mcve] to help others help you.

Answer (score -2):

yourRDateHere <- read.csv("data_raw", header = TRUE)